# Example for Lévy's continuity theorem

Tags: probability-theory, examples-counterexamples, weak-convergence, characteristic-functions, probability-limit-theorems

I am searching a sequence of RV $(X_n)$ for which we prove a convergence in distribution to a random variable $X$, using the fact that the characteristic functions $(\varphi_n)_n$ converges pointwise to some function $\varphi$ which is continuous at $0$, with **$\varphi$ not the characteristic function of a well-know law** (Binomial, Cauchy, Normal, etc).

Thanks